# Saving TableView cell using UserDefaults

Tags: swift, tableview, userdefaults

I'm trying to get cell of tableView using UserDefaults, but after i reload app it is always empty

This is my Model:

```
struct Note: Codable {
    var title: String
    var description: String
}

class Notes {
    var stock: [Note] = []
}
```

View contoller

```
var model = Notes()
```

This is how i get data

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
        tableView.reloadData()

if let fetchedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notes") {
            let fetchedBookies = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Note].self, from: fetchedData)
            print(fetchedBookies)
        } else {
            model.stock = []
        }
}
```

This is my cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.titleOutlet.text = self.model.stock[indexPath.row].title
        cell.descriptionOutlet?.text = self.model.stock[indexPath.row].description
        return cell
    }
```

How i save data

```
@IBAction func check(_ sender: Any) {
        let newstock = Note(title: "check", description: "check2")
        model.stock.append(newstock)
        print(model.stock.count)
        
        
        let bookiesData = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(model.stock)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bookiesData, forKey: "notes")

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you forgot `model.stock = fetchedBookies` after loading from User Defaults

Comment: Thank you very much. It is about 2 hours i was trying to find an error lol

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Json Encoder/Deocder.

First set your `Notes` class to conform to Codable:

```swift
class Notes: Codable {
    var stock: [Note] = []
}
```

Here is an example of how to use Json Encoder / Decoder:

```swift
func save(notes: Notes) throws {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(notes)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
    } catch let error {
        throw error
    }
}

func load() -> Notes {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notes") else {
        return Notes() // Default
    }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let object = try decoder.decode(Notes.self, from: data)
        return object
    } catch {
        return Notes() // Default
    }
}
```

In your code just call `load()` to get your notes from User Defaults

And `save(notes:)` to save them into User Defaults.